# Bypass the dependency of jaxb-core in optaplanner due to license related issue

Tags: jaxb, licensing, optaplanner

I am developing an optimization tool using Optaplanner 8.34.0 for a commercial product. However, the rules of my organization prevent the use of JAXB core due to certain license issues.

I am not sure if I am making use of the JAXB core jar. Can it be removed without causing any other issues with the optimization ? Or is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is required to serialize and deserialize solver configs.
Even if you don't use that functionality, and only use solver config Java APIs, JAXB annotations are still present on those classes.
From that, I expect that JAXB is a hard dependency and removing it is not going to be possible.
That said, we never tried, neither in OptaPlanner, nor in [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/).